# ContextMenuStrip Hide and UnHide Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I'm working on a System Tray Application for a project. I'm currently stuck on when I click on "Toggle On" it won't change itself to "Toggle Off", I was hoping that maybe someone could tell me what i'm doing wrong and help me with fixing it.

Code for the Context Menu

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TestApplicationforRIVC.Properties;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TestApplicationforRIVC {

    class RIVCContextMenu {

        //Is Add Box Displayed?
        bool isAddLoaded = false;

        //Is the Clear box Displayed?
        bool isClearLoaded = false;

        //Is it listening for voice?
        bool toggleOn = false;

        //Creates this Instance
        public ContextMenuStrip Create() {
            //Add the Default Menu Options
            ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
            ToolStripMenuItem item;
            ToolStripMenuItem off;
            ToolStripSeparator sep;

            if(toggleOn) {
                //Toggle Off
                item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                item.Text = "Toggle Off";
                item.Click += new EventHandler(toggleOffClick);
                item.Image = Resources.toggleOff;
                menu.Items.Add(item);
            }
            if(!toggleOn) {
                //Toggle On
                item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                item.Text = "Toggle On";
                item.Click += new EventHandler(toggleOnClick);
                item.Image = Resources.toggleOn;
                menu.Items.Add(item);
            }
            // Separator.
            sep = new ToolStripSeparator();
            menu.Items.Add(sep);

            //Add to RIVC Library
            item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            item.Text = "Add to Library";
            item.Click += new EventHandler(addClick);
            item.Image = Resources.Add;
            menu.Items.Add(item);

            //Clear RIVC Library
            item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            item.Text = "Clear Library";
            item.Click += new EventHandler(clearClick);
            item.Image = Resources.Delete;
            menu.Items.Add(item);

            // Separator.
            sep = new ToolStripSeparator();
            menu.Items.Add(sep);

            //Exit Program
            item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            item.Text = "Exit";
            item.Click += new System.EventHandler(exitClick);
            item.Image = Resources.Exit;
            menu.Items.Add(item);

            return menu;
        }

        //Handles the Click Event of the Toggle On Control
        void toggleOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            toggleOn = true;
        }

        //Handles the Click Even of the Toggle Off Control
        void toggleOffClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            toggleOn = false;
        }

        //Handles the Click Event of the Add Control
        void addClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if(!isAddLoaded) {
                isAddLoaded = true;
                //enter Dialog Box Info
                isAddLoaded = false;
            }
        }

        //Handles the Click Event of the Clear Control
        void clearClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if(!isClearLoaded) {
                isClearLoaded = true;
                //enter dialog box info
                isClearLoaded = false;
            }
        }

        //Handles the Click Event of the Exit Control
        void exitClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully You guys can help me out with solving this little bug.

Comment: Why create a completely new menu each time?  Why not just change the .Text() property of the ToolStripMenuItem() in the Click handler?

Comment: When you click on "Toggle On" you just change the 'toggleOn' field to 'true'. Do you create a new instance of the ContextMenuStrip?
I would suggest you to do what @Idle_Mind suggested and change the Text, then you can have single handler to change 'toggleOn'.

Answer (score 0):

You just need 1 menu item for the `toggle on/off` like this:

```
item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item.Name = "onOff";//Name it to refer later if needed
item.Text = "Toggle Off";
item.Click += new EventHandler(toggleOnOffClick);
item.Image = Resources.toggleOff;
menu.Items.Add(item);
```

Note that, the toggle on/off item need some *initialized state*, suppose it's the *off* state (that means the initialized value of `toggleOn` should be `false`). Here is the new `toggleOnOffClick` event handler for you:

```
void toggleOnOffClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
  if(toggleOn){
    item.Text = "Toggle off";
    item.Image = Resources.toggleOff;
  } else {
    item.Text = "Toggle on";
    item.Image = Resources.toggleOn;
  }
  toggleOn = !toggleOn;
}
```